# how to find a number phrase in php which at least have 2 digit

Tags: php

i try to use a rss code , i want get codes of rss and find a number phrase in it, here is the markup :

```
bokk 1 is there 23453
shot 3 ao adfsdf 348943
aadd 4 asdis 4321334
adfie 9 aioe 938
```

how define a pattern to push numbers which have a leat to digit in an array in php language ?

i think eregi() functions can be useable, but don't know how use it,
for more explain , first line has a 5 digit number(23453) and second line has a 6 digit number(348943) and so on... how to save these number in an array where at leat has 2 digit and the numbers of digit is unlimited,

Comment: "i think eregi() functions can be useable" I think not considering the `ereg*` functions have been deprecated for a couple of years now. :-) Look into `preg_*` functions

Comment: huh..? can you please correct your grammar and spelling; i'm having a hard time trying to figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]{2,})/", $string, $match);
```

Comment: what is $match ? what should be $match?

Comment: $m is result, $m[1] is array of group 1 (digits in this case) http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php